# Webpack, React and foundation icons

Tags: reactjs, webpack, icons

I installed foundation-icons via npm. How can I configure my webpack config to just include  tag with needed classname in component render method?

Comment: put a snippet code before vote down comes as storm 

Answer (score 1):

Here's how, I grabbed this webpack config from [foundation-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/foundation-icons) package itself.

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // the url-loader uses DataUrls. 
      // the file-loader emits files. 
      { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
    ]
  }
};
```

Don't forget to install the loaders:

```
npm install url-loader --save-dev
npm install file-loader --save-dev
```

Finally, import foundation-icons.css from App.js and use your specific foundation icon.

```
import 'foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css';

import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <i className="step fi-like size-48"></i>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Looks fairly simple. I've not tried this though.